# Referencing another equation in an align

Tags: cross-referencing, subequations

I'd like to define a set of equations, where one equation is introduced earlier than the others, but it should still become clear that they belong together going forward.

The MWE

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    This is the first equation:
    \begin{equation} \label{eq:first}
        x = y + z
    \end{equation}
    But there's more! The full system of equations is
    \begin{subequations} \label{eq:system}
        \begin{align}
            w &= v + u \\
            a &= b + c \\
            &\cref{eq:first} \nonumber \text{.}
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}
    To solve the system \cref{eq:system} we...
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of MWE]

produces something that is unsatisfying in that

1. the extra equation number looks out of place (especially if one configures `cleveref` to omit the "eq." label) and
2. referencing eq. 2, it is not clear if eq. 1 is also included (i.e. "is (1) really (2c)?").

How to do this in a standard way?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by "misaligned" and why the "numbering is weird"?

Comment: @Werner I've updated the question, trying to explain.

Comment: why do you want the `\cref` _in_ the align? That will  look weird whatever you do. What meaning is implied by the alignment if you align = with "eq (1)" ? It would be far more natural to have the reference in the sentence introducing the alignment

Comment: @DavidCarlisle fair question. I came across this "style" once in the literature (though I can't remember in which of the dozen books I skimmed through recently this was). And I just liked the style, because it nicely packaged everything together in one block while also acknowledging the pre-existence of one of the equations. If I ever find that example again, I'll post it as reference.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think I saw this in the slightly different setting of an optimization problem statement, where it said "minimize f(x) <newline> subject to (5), (6), <newline> <more eqs>".

Comment: @Xaser: Unfortunately this question remains subjective.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Adaptations

- Use `aligned` if you want aligned equations to get the same tag
- Use `\mathllap` to allow for aligned `=` between `align` and `aligned`

Basmah

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    
    This is the first equation
    \begin{subequations}
        \begin{align}
            x &= y + z
            \label{eq:first}
            \shortintertext{but there's more. The full system of equations is}
            &
            \begin{aligned}
                \mathllap{w} &= v + u \\
                \mathllap{a} &= b + c
            \end{aligned}
            \label{eq:system}
        \end{align}
    \end{subequations}
    
    To solve the system \cref{eq:first,eq:system} we...
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that doesn't quite do it for me, because in the real example, there's much more text in between (at least as much that it doesn't qualify the use of \shortintertext. But at least I now know about \mathllap, so that's cool!